# eventfd, adds values written to socket

Tags: c++, c, linux

Following is the issue,

I have one listener thread, that listens and accepts new connections.
Once accepted, I use eventfd to pass on socket descriptor to four other worker threads.
listener is the one that creates one eventfd, and all worker threads read the same.

Now issue is, when multiple clients connect to server, server listener accepts the connections, and writes to eventfd, and one of the worker thread receives sum of two different sockets.
For example, if two connections were accepted on sockets 10 and 11, one of the worker receives 21.

Now, it could be by design, however, it makes no sense to me, why writes are not queue rather than getting added.

Please correct me if wrong, also let me know if anyone would like to see sample code.

Comment: Could you provide sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. `eventfd()` is a *something happened* notification tool, not a *something happened; here's the relevant data* tool.

When you write a new 64 bit integer value to the eventfd, it's added to the current number associated with the event. Reading from the descriptor gives you the current number and resets it to 0 (assuming you're not using semaphore mode). So if you write twice and only then read, you get behavior like you describe.

You should use a queue or some other mechanism to pass the socket descriptors to your threads.

Comment: I can use queue, but it introduces races to the equation, eventfd, if it did what I expected makes implementation way cleaner and performant. I think as you say, it is by design, I would have loved if there was a mechanism in place where I could achieve what I explained.

Comment: @SushilLakra It'd have to be a thread safe queue structure, of course. Something as simple as a datagram `socketpair()` would probably work.

Comment: One of a number of other alternatives is to have multiple threads calling `accept()`; only one will get a new connection at a time.

Comment: There are many solutions to what I want to achieve, however your response is good enough for me to reevaluate the implementation as eventfd does not suffice for my purpose.

Comment: And thanks for help, prompt response is highly appreciated.